# RangeError BITFIELD_INVALID: Invalid bitfield flag or number

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am Trying to make a discord bot that automatically makes a mute role on a command without the ability to send messages/add reactions

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

```
if (command === 'setup'){
    let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(m => m.name === "Muted");


message.guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: 'Muted',
    color: 'BLACK',
    permissions: {
      SEND_MESSAGES: false,
      ADD_REACTIONS: false
       }
  },
})
  .catch(console.error);
}
```

```
RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number.
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\Public\ShieldBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:150:19)
    at RoleManager.create (C:\Users\Public\ShieldBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\RoleManager.js:112:58)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Public\ShieldBot\main.js:209:21)
    at Client.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Public\ShieldBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Public\ShieldBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Public\ShieldBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Public\ShieldBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Public\ShieldBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Public\ShieldBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16) {
  bit: { SEND_MESSAGES: false, ADD_REACTIONS: false },
  [Symbol(code)]: 'BITFIELD_INVALID'
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`RoleData.permissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RoleData) is a `PermissionResolvable` or an array of `PermissionResolvable` and not an object .

If you don't want to grant any permissions to the newly created role, you can do

```js
message.guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: 'Muted',
    color: 'BLACK',
    permissions: [],
  },
});
```